# how to prevent priority queue from having duplicate values at c++

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

now I'm trying to use priority queue in c++ like this

```cpp
struct compare
{
    bool operator()(const int &a, const int &b)
    {
        return weight[a] < weight[b];
    }
};
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, compare> q;
```

**but I want it to ignore any duplicate values**

Is it possible using any technique to do this?

or should I build my priority_queue DS

Comment: What does it even mean to *ignore any duplicate values* for a `compare`?

Comment: Instead of a `priority_queue`, why not use a `std::set`?

Comment: @Eljay if the pq includes values { 1, 2, 5} and I inserted 2 for example 
I want it to insert 2 again 
I want the pq to have 2 once due to the new weight
does the explanation clear?

Comment: Yet another try (but a rather dirty one) might be a custom container wrapping around a *pointer* to vector – passing that one to the copy or move constructor, while actually *not* copying or moving – Then you could iterate over (or even do a binary search in) the pointed vector before inserting into the queue. But make sure to wrap all that with yet another class to have a clean interface!

Comment: @Eljay if the pq includes values { 1, 2, 5} and I inserted 2 for example 
I want it to insert 2 again 
I want the pq to have 2 once due to the new weight
does the explanation clear?

Comment: @NathanOliver
i want to insert due to some priority

Comment: @NathanOliver 's idea is to use a set because that one is sorted as well in C++ – the custom comparator of the set would then consider your priorities – so `begin()` would give you the object with highest priority. `std::set::insert` prevents entering duplicates – thus you'd be fine with.

Comment: @NathanOliver nice idea 
thanks;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is creating a custom container for the `std::priority_queue`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Vector : public std::vector<T>
{
public:
    using std::vector<T>::vector;

    void push_back(const T &value)
    {
        if (std::find(this->begin(), this->end(), value) == this->end()) std::vector<T>::push_back(value);
    }
};

int main()  //
{
    std::vector<int> data = {0, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4};
    std::vector<float> weight = {.3, .1, .6, .2, .5};
    auto comp = [&weight](int first, int second) { return weight[first] < weight[second]; };

    std::priority_queue<int, Vector<int>, decltype(comp)> queue(comp);

    for (auto item : data) queue.push(item);

    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        cout << queue.top() << ", ";
        queue.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Here I have inherited from `std::vector` and changed the `push_back` method to detect duplicates.

But this is the efficient way of doing it (has complexity `O(n)`). We can create a custom queue with the same `top, pop, empty, size, push` functions as `std::priority_queue`:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename C>
class Queue
{
    std::set<T, C> impl;

public:
    Queue(C compare) : impl(compare) {}

    const T &top() const { return *impl.begin(); }

    void pop() { impl.erase(impl.begin()); }

    bool empty() const { return impl.empty(); }

    std::size_t size() const { return impl.size(); }

    void push(const T &value) { impl.insert(value); }
};

int main()  //
{
    std::vector<int> data = {0, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4};
    std::vector<float> weight = {.3, .1, .6, .2, .5};
    auto comp = [&weight](int first, int second) { return weight[first] > weight[second]; };

    Queue<int, decltype(comp)> queue(comp);

    for (auto item : data) queue.push(item);

    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        cout << queue.top() << ", ";
        queue.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This method uses `std::set` to keep the order and has faster duplicate detection (has complexity `O(log(n))`).

Comment: thanks, a lot 
It's exactly what I wanted

Comment: @OmarFareed Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your question. This is important for others who come here for help.

Comment: I did, thanks;;